# Wix - uninstall different product

Tags: windows, installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Our main installer is calling another product (product B) installer
This creates two entries in the ""add remove programs" window.
When I uninstall the main product product B is not removed from machine.
Is there a way that I can uninstall product B when the main product is uninstalled?

Comment: I think the down vote may have not understood your problem clearly.  I would, however, suggest using the WiX chaining tools to install your multiple products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) with these settings:

- it should be scheduled after InstallFinalize in InstallExecuteSequence
- it should use this condition:

  REMOVE = "ALL"
- use **ExeCommand** attribute to specify the msiexec.exe uninstall command line (you will use the actual ProductCode):

  msiexec.exe /x <product_code_B> /qb
- set **Return** attribute to *asyncNoWait* so product B uninstall runs in a different process