# Two WIX bundles with same upgrade code - Uninstall one?

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I have two different products both of which uses their own Wix Bundles and MSIs (one MSI each). While the UpgradeCode in each MSI is different, both the bundles ended up sharing the same UpgradeCode in their bootstrappers.

Is there a way to structure the MSIs or Bundles so that each product when installed uninstall the other one if detected while allowing its own major upgrades to go through?

Version of WIX: 3.10

Answer (score 0):

An MSI can have more then one MajorUpgrade rule.  That is Product B can have a rule that searches for Product A and remove it.   Same for A to remove B.  This way the two MSI will always be mutually exclusive and will major upgrade them selves.

The bootstrapper part I think isn't a factor here.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Would you have an example on how to do this? In my registry I see an entry with the BundleUpradeCode (which is the same between the two products) and not the MSI Upgrade Code (which is different). Hence the confusion.

Comment: In the MSI itself.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732240/how-do-you-uninstall-another-program-in-wix-installer

Comment: Thanks. I do have a Bootstrapper to uninstall, not just an MSI so that isn't relevant for my case.