# WIX build error ICE61: Upgrade.ActionProperty ... cannot be authored in the Property table

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I was applying this post's top solution
[How do you uninstall another program in wix installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732240/how-do-you-uninstall-another-program-in-wix-installer) to uninstall an older version of a product.

*product.wxs*

```xml
<Property Id="OLD_VERSION" Secure="yes" Value="{53...}" />
        
<Upgrade Id="EA...">
    <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="OLD_VERSION" Minimum="0.0.0" Maximum="19.0.0" />
</Upgrade>
```

The msi package is built and I can run it and the upgrade process seems to work however I get this error on VS (which breaks devops).

`ICE61: Upgrade.ActionProperty OLD_VERSION cannot be authored in the Property table`.

Is there any way I can fix this other than suppress ICE61 in the Project Pettings > Tool Settings tab in Visual Studio?

I'm using WIX 3.11.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want a package to upgrade another product, add a new `Upgrade`/`UpgradeVersion` pair with the upgrade code of the old product.