# Uninstall different product at install and major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Two different products have different UpgradeCodes and exist in two different setups (ProductA.msi and ProductB.msi). Both have version N.

Now ProductB is *merged* into ProductA version N+1. That is, ProductB's files will be provided by the installer of ProductA, and to the install location of ProductA.

A user that installs ProductA version N+1 would not like ProductB to be installed any more (it could even cause problems). So when ProductA is installed/upgraded to version N+1,  ProductB (any version) should be removed. How can I accomplish this in the setup of ProductA?

It's similar to this question, but that is for removing a different product at *uninstall* rather than at install/upgrade. [Wix - uninstall different product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483669/wix-uninstall-different-product)

Comment: Well, you can try to use different conditions, `NOT Installed` and `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` instead of `REMOVE="ALL"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***WiX Sample***: Here is a technical sample of doing as Bob Arnson describes: **[Adding entries to MSI UpgradeTable to remove related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801570/adding-entries-to-msi-upgradetable-to-remove-related-products/51803320#51803320)**. Make sure you leave this entry in your setup for future releases. It needs to persist there as people can skip a few version when upgrading?

***Inline Sample***: Please see link above for full sample.

```
<!-- Older Product Line 1: Upgrade Code -->
<Upgrade Id="{11111111-1111-1111-1111-000000000000}">
   <UpgradeVersion Property="PRODUCTLINE1" IncludeMinimum="yes" Minimum="0.0.0" />
</Upgrade>
```

---

***Debugging Major Upgrades***: [WIX does not uninstall older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989906/wix-does-not-uninstall-older-version/56991527#56991527) - an ad-hoc list of causes for  major upgrade failure.

---

***Component Referencing***: Merging setups can cause some component reference errors. I assume you are aware. This could manifest as missing files after installation or "some malfunction" during upgrade scenarios. Faulty registration, stranded files, you name it - just mentioning.

- ***Component GUIDs***: Here is some background information on component referencing and component GUIDs: [Change my component GUID in wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121)
- ***As a rule of thumb***: If you install the old files to a new location with new component GUIDs you should be fine. Things to check: shared files, COM servers, anything unsual in terms of machine-scope registration, services, COM Interop, COM+, etc... Many setups are simple, [others are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733889/what-is-the-benefit-and-real-purpose-of-program-installation/22737069#22737069).
- ***Custom Actions***: Migrating any custom actions can cause serious problems - especially during upgrade scenarios with complex sequencing and conditioning for when the actions actually run and not.

Answer (score 1):

Add ProductB's upgrade code to a new [`Upgrade` element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/upgrade.html) in ProductA. Then when installing ProductA N+1, the upgrade will remove both ProductA N and ProductB.